# Whether the use of the tense is acceptable or not?

Tags: grammar

Which of the following sentences is correct? I also would like to know whether the use of the tense is acceptable or not.

> 1. The result of the lack of a strong gravitational pull is that it has caused any water the moon may have had to leak out into space.
> 2. The result of the lack of a strong gravitational pull has caused any water the moon may have had to leak out into space.

Comment: Ditch ***the result of*** - it's an awkward construction here. *The lack of a strong gravitational pull has caused any water the moon may have had to leak out into space.* Personally, I have reservations about saying a ***lack*** of something (ie. - non-existence) ***caused*** something else to happen in this exact context, since that "missing gravity" is hardly something that the Moon could or should have had (unless it was made of something really dense, such as solid gold).

Comment: Alternatively, *The result of the lack of a strong gravitational pull **is that** any water the moon may have had **has** leaked out into space*. That's not great, but it's better than any variant where *the result of [something] **caused** [something else]*. Personally I'd rather rephrase to something like *Any water the Moon may have had **will have leaked** out into space **because of** the low gravity.*

Comment: Thanks, FumbleFingers. If I rewrite the sentence like the following, is it correct? There is no strong gravitational pull on the moon. The result has caused any water the moon may have had to leak out into space.

Comment: As I just said, I *personally* don't think it usually works to say that "a result" can ***cause*** something. Irrelevant, I know, but it's my understanding that most of the surface water on Earth arrived here in the [Late Heavy Bombardment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_Heavy_Bombardment), so it's not so much that a lack of gravity allowed the water to leak away from the Moon - it's more that the water-filled comets didn't fall on the Moon so much in the first place because it has a lower gravitational pull than Earth, which therefore attracted most of those comets.

Comment: @ FumbleFingers. I read a sentence: The Brexit result has caused a financial earthquake. You can see the sentence in https://www.eng.cecabank.es>resulta... .

Comment: In a context like that, it wouldn't be unreasonable to say *The Government's **lack** of a clear mandate caused a financial earthquake*, or even ***The result** of the Government's **lack** of a clear mandate **was*** a financial earthquake*, but normally we don't say *the **result** [of some situation] **caused** something* - idiomatically, it's usually either ***something caused** [this outcome]* or ***the result is** [this outcome]*.